# Public Pacemaker database online?

Tags: cardiology, research-process

I am looking for any database about pacemakers with the leads

- atria A
- right ventricle VR
- left ventricle VL

I did not find any in Physionet.

**Is there any anonymous data about different situations online or accessible by request?**